# Money-Rails is discarding price amount after decimal point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, money-rails

I am building and Rails 5 API where I am trying to send money amount and store it in PostgresQL database. I am sending amount 2.4 but I see in database only 2 is stored. what I am doing wrong?

my migration:

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
  create_table :transactions do |t|
   t.monetize :transaction_price, amount: { null: true, default: nil }
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

my model is:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  monetize :transaction_price_cents
end
```

my controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApiController
      def create
        transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_param)
        if transaction.save
          render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', data:transaction }, status: :ok
        end
      end

      private
      def transaction_param
        params.require(:transaction).permit(:transaction_price_cents)
      end
end
```

I am sending this json with postman:

```
{
    "transaction_price_cents": 345.23
}
```

What I am getting in response:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "transaction_price_cents": 345,
        "transaction_price_currency": "USD",
    }
}
```

I either want 345.23 or 34523 but its giving me only 345!

Comment: Shouldn't the ammount be 100 times greater if you want to do the logic in dollars? It's even in the name associated to the value `transaction_price_cent`.

Comment: I din get exactly. 
Did you mean I have to multiply the price with 100 (I mean make it cents) before sending it to database? I thought the Gem will do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your price in cents! And that's ok!

Handling money in cents is a common pattern. It will also save your life when it comes to rounding errors with taxes or currency exchange. Like in their docs mentioned you should use a helper to output the price in a human readable form:

```
humanized_money @money_object                       # => 6.50
humanized_money_with_symbol @money_object           # => $6.50
money_without_cents_and_with_symbol @money_object   # => $6
```

If you accessing the data via an API you could add a human_readable field in your api

```
def transaction_price_human_readable
  return humanized_money_with_symbol(@money_object) # or self or...
end
```

---

Save/Create model: If you get a floating number you could change the floating point into cents before_save

```
before_save :convert_transaction_price
def convert_transaction_price
   self.transaction_price = (self.transaction_price * 100).to_i
end
```

Comment: so, when I am sending price, I should be sending in cents? 
like if I have $345.23 then I have to send it like 43523? is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, you also have to save the price in cents. you can do this in a before_save action

Comment: You should also check your migration. In the docs they say something about "*_cents" in the attribute name...

Comment: Hi, I have tried this 
`before_save :convert_transaction_price
def convert_transaction_price
   self.transaction_price = (self.transaction_price * 100).to_i
end` But it still showing me wrong value. Now, it shows me 23400 instead of 23423. am I missing anything?

Comment: Actually I am having exactly this problem: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/issues/396 Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Ok remove the before_save . Are you getting the correct value in cents?

Comment: Let's hope the authors of the plugin will help

Comment: It doesn't matter even if I remove the before_save .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
**(EDITED NEW AND CORRECT ANSWER):**

All I had to do was to use the provided attribute from the money-rails gem. In my case I had an `amount_cents` attribute, and I had to use the provided `:amount` attribute in the form.

```
<%= f.label :amount %>
<%= f.text_field :amount %>
```

**NOTE:** I converted the value of `:amount_cents` to a float string in the `edit.html.erb` as followed:

```
<%= f.label :amount %>
<%= f.text_field :amount, value: number_with_precision(f.object.amount_cents / 100, precision: 2).gsub(/\./, ',') %>
```

(**also note** that I had configured money-rails to use EUROs which use "," as delimiter, thats why i have to use `.gsbu(/\./, ',')`)

And here ist the **IMPORTANT PART**, I had to update my **strong_parameters** in the controller to permit `:amount`, and not `:amount_cents`

```
    private

        def invoice_params
            params.require(:invoice).permit(…, :amount, …)
        end
```

--

**(OLD ANSWER):**
I came to the conclusion that it is best to change the input value directly in the Frontend to cents. And then send the cents to the backend.

Here is a nice Stimulus Controller which does exactly that: https://gist.github.com/psergi/72f99b792a967525ffe2e319cf746101
(You may need to update that gist to your liking, and also it expects that you use Stimulus in your rails project)

(I leave the old answer in here, because I think it is a good practice to send _cents  from the frontend to the backend, but in the moment it is not necessary [for me]. If you want to support more than one currency, you probably want to do it like that and use a .js framework to handle the input conversion -> s.th. like http://autonumeric.org/)